# Error compiling Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, string, package, manifest

I was translating an app and I did everything right ...

Decompile the apk
Translate app (res / values / string.xml)
And I compile again

But now the time to compile the following error appears **"Error: Android Generator Source: [project] Package is not specified in AndroidManifest.xml"**

What to do? I did not change anything beyond the translation.

Comment: What's your manifest look like?

Comment: You also may have invalid characters in your XML - translating can lead to weird errors like that. Post your manifest.xml, but also look into those files to make sure they translated correctly.

Comment: In the test I did in AVD is translated, but it does not open also appears a mistake, and manifest in these parts appears in red.

Follows the manisfest http://oi61.tinypic.com/10pdngx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In the test I did in AVD is translated, but it does not open also appears a mistake, and manifest in these parts appears in red.

Follows the manisfest http://oi61.tinypic.com/10pdngx.jpg